# How does comet work with the client side

Tags: apache, tomcat, comet

I have a question with regards to the comet implementation. I know that it is used to handle asynchronous requests similar to what now can be achieved through Servlet 3.0 async functionality. Yet what i do not understand is how the push is done to the calling client.

In web sockets we open the connection by providing the ip and port. With comet, how do you connect with the server in order to receive call backs when the server pushes data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on [Comet (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) is a pretty good resource for this question (sorry it's so obvious).

Comet is an umbrella term for using HTTP to simulate a bi-directional connection between a client and server. Ultimately you make an HTTP request to the server and attempt to hold it open (long polling and streaming). With long-polling that connection closes after a given interval or when data is returned. With streaming the connection is help open as long as possible and new data is sent over the existing connection.

How these are achieved differ between web browsers - that why Comet is classed as a hack. Again, the wikipedia page should provide almost all the information you need.

I wrote an article covering the history of realtime web communication (with a focus on client) and why [WebSockets are a game-changer](http://pusher.com/websockets).

Comment: Thx alot. My issue was that long polling is just recursive ajax calling and hence not the same as websockets right? anyway the wiki did kind of cover it and thank you for your article. Will go through that as well.

Comment: @dinukadev It's important to remember that Comet isn't just long-polling - they are not synonymous since long polling is just one of the ways Comet is achieved. Streaming is actually a better solution since the connection is kept open and information can instantly be sent. With long polling there are times where no connection is established and data could be out of date (stale). Pleased I could help.